# Batch add basename to another file

Tags: command-line, rename, filenames, batch-rename

I screwed up with mmv and deleted a few characters from the end of the filenames in a folder (before the extension).

Luckily I have other files with the same original basename but with a different extension.
I would like to know whether there is a way make a loop:

- To match the remainder of the basename from the modified file to the second file with the original filename.
- If it matches, rename the file with the original filename

Example:

```
Wrong filenames: foo-1234.txt 
                 foo-1225.txt
Right files:    foo-1234-5678.png
                foo-1225-6789.png
```

Desired output:

```
foo-1234-5678.txt
foo-1225-6789.txt
```

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't mention what environment we are talking about, but I'm assuming it's Windows cmd. You can try this:

```
  @echo off
  setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
  for %%f in (foo-*.png) do set f=%%f & rename !f:~0,8!.txt !f:~0,13!.txt
```

It must be executed from batch file - delayed expansion won't work from direct command line.

**EDIT**

powershell counterpart:

```
dir foo-*.png | % { $stem = $_.name -replace 'foo-([^.]+).png','$1'; $bad = $stem.substring(0,4); mv foo-$bad.txt foo-$stem.txt; }
```

bash:

```sh
for file in foo-*.png; do stem=${file:4:9}; bad=${file:4:4}; mv foo-${bad}.txt foo-${stem}.txt; done
```

Comment: Yes sorry, I am on bash. Could you explain what `do stem=${file:4:9}; bad=${file:4:4}` means? I am not sure I understand what it does so I can modify it at will. Thanks!

Comment: Expression `${file:4:9}` gives 9 charactes from variable file, starting at fifth (it's 0-based). See https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html for more details.

Comment: Actually in this case, this would be less confusing: `for file in foo-*.png; do mv ${file:0:8}.txt ${file:0:13}.txt; done`